# How to make formulae take equal vertical space in the align environment?

Tags: align, line-spacing

Consider the following code:

```
\begin{align}
f_1(x) &= \frac{15x}{3} \\
f_2(x) &= 3x + 5 \\
f_3(x) &= 4x + 13
\end{align}
```

This produces three lines where the first line takes up more vertical space than the others. Is there any way to make all the lines take the same vertical space (meaning effectively all lines take as much vertical space as the largest one)?

Comment: Opposite question (make the distance between the lowest point of previous row and highest point of next row equal): [math mode - Vertical Spacing within align environment accounting for fractions - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54587/vertical-spacing-within-align-environment-accounting-for-fractions)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I don't know of an automatic way to do this, but in a particular case, you can use `\vphantom` to effect this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
f_1(x) &= \frac{15x}{3} \\
f_2(x) &= \vphantom{\frac11}3x + 5 \\
f_3(x) &= \vphantom{\frac11}4x + 13
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: [“These fracs go to eleven”](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Up_to_eleven) ;-)

Answer (score 16):

if you do not want it globally changed put the complete formula into `{...}`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\savebox\strutbox{$\vphantom{\dfrac11}$}
\begin{align}
  f_1(x) &= \frac{15x}{3} \\
  f_2(x) &= 3x + 5 \\
  f_3(x) &= 4x + 13
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Despite the additional white space below the display, this is definitely most elegant.

Comment: Beautiful! How exactly does it work?

Comment: `\vphantom{...}` defines  box of width zero and height nof its contents. Which is the height of a fraction "1/1".  `\strutbox` is used by `align` for every row.

Comment: This is very useful, thank you. Would this only affect the following `align` environment? Or all the way down to the end of the document?

Comment: @DaneelOlivaw it's a normal tex local assignment so has the same scope as a font change or `\renewcommand` etc, the current group or environment (which is `document` here, but could be any local scope from `{}` or `minipage` etc.

Answer (score 5):

I can offer a variant of TH's answer that produces a bit less vertical space, but it is adjusted to your particular situation: Only the *second* line needs a bit of additional *depth*. The advantage of this more special adjustment is that it doesn't produce additional white space *below* the display.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
Here's some text just to fill the line sufficiently
\begin{align}
f_1(x) &= \frac{15x}{3} \\
f_2(x) &= 3x + 5 \vphantom{\smash[t]{\frac11}} \\
f_3(x) &= 4x + 13
\end{align}
Here's some text just to fill the line sufficiently
\end{document}
```

[image]