# Weird alignment in

Tags: matrices

For some reason, the following code compiles as shown on the picture.

```
\begin{equation}
    t_{0\rightarrow1}
    \equiv\frac{1}{2}(X-iY)
    = \begin{pmatrix}
       0 & 0 \\
       1 & 0
      \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
```

Where is this extra space at the bottom coming from, and how do I remove it? It looks like the parenthesis are correctly vertically aligned, but the rows are not... Also, clearly, the parenthesis are too big.

[image]

**UPDATE: RESOLUTION**

So it turned out that earlier in the code I used the solution from [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9147/how-to-make-formulae-take-equal-vertical-space-in-the-align-environment/9151) answer to align my equations nicely. Namely, I added a line

```
\savebox\strutbox{$\vphantom{\sum\limits_{k}}$}
```

to my code. However, I forgot to put the equation into `{}`, and so this caused the weird alignment later.

Comment: A minimal example from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}` is needed. Are you using `setspace`?

Comment: ...especially since the code doesn't match the image.

Answer (score 4):

There is nothing wrong with your code.

The MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
t_{0\rightarrow1}
\equiv\frac{1}{2}(X-iY)
= \begin{pmatrix}
   0 & 0 \\
   1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

results in the following output.

[image: Output of the MWE.]

There seems to be a side-effect due to another package loaded. You can add the other packages you employ one by one and thereby determine where the problem comes from.

Comment: Thanks, will try.