# amsmath equal row spacing

Tags: align, amsmath

I would like to display these equations in an alignment:

```
\begin{align}
%\setlength{\jot}{20pt}
V_\text{SET} &= min \Bigg( \frac{dV}{dI} \Bigg) &\text{for } V<0 \\[1em]
I_\text{SET} &= I(argmin \Bigg( \frac{dV}{dI} \Bigg) -3 ) &\text{for } V<0\\[1em]
V_\text{RESET} &= V(arg(grad(smooth(I)) \leqslant 0)(0)) &\text{for } V>0\\[1em]
I_\text{RESET} &= I(arg(grad(smooth(I)) \leqslant 0)(0)) &\text{for } V>0\\[1em]
V_\text{SET,stop} &= min(V) \\[1em]
V_\text{RESET,stop} &= max(V) \\[1em]
I_\text{cc} &= min(I) \\[1em]
Lin &= I(V=\pm 0.4)/I(V=\pm 0.2)
\end{align}
```

I already tried setting the length of jot and using [1em]. However due to the fractions the spacing between the lines is not equal and I can not get it to be equal. This is what it looks like now:

[image]

Also due to [1em] the equations are now longer than the page and are over the page number, as you can see on the right bottom (13).
I am relatively new to Latex so I hope this not very obvious. Any help is appreciated.
Thanks so much in advance :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make formulae take equal vertical space in the align environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9147/how-to-make-formulae-take-equal-vertical-space-in-the-align-environment)

Comment: To allow page breaks in a multi-line display math environment provided by the `amsmath` package, insert `\allowdisplaybreaks` *before* the `align` environment in question.

Comment: @campa - This query is *not* a duplicate of the earlier posting you provided a link to. The accepted & most-upvoted answer of the earlier posting recommended inserted tall typographic struts (constructed with `\vphantom` directives) in the rows that don't natively contain "tall" material. For the case at hand, this approach would create a rather suboptimal outcome. As I argue in my answer, it would be much better to use `\smash[b]` and `\smash` directives in the first two rows than it is to make the remaining six rows gratuitously and unnecessarily tall via `\vphantom` directives.

Comment: @Mico Uhm, I trust your judgment, but while I agree that the answers in the linked question are sub-optimal for the present case, the question title is basically the same...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case of your equations, it suffices to change `\Bigg` to `\Big` and to `\smash` the expressions involving tall parentheses in order to get a more compact display in the vertical dimension. With this change, one can dispense with the `[1em]` spacing directives. To get more compactness in the *horizontal dimension* as well, it's a good idea to employ an `alignat` environment rather than an `align` environment.

A separate comment: the terms "max", "min", "arg" etc are math operators; to typeset them using an upright font face, input them as `\max`, `\min`, `\arg`, etc.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,array}
\DeclareMathOperator{\argmin}{arg\,min}
\DeclareMathOperator{\grad}{grad}
\DeclareMathOperator{\smooth}{smooth}
\begin{document}

\begin{alignat}{2}
V_{\textrm{SET}}   &= \min \smash[b]{\Bigl( \frac{dV}{dI} \Bigr)} 
   &\quad&\text{for $V<0$} \\[1em]
I_{\textrm{SET}}   &= I\smash{\Bigl(\argmin \Bigl( \frac{dV}{dI} \Bigr) -3 \Bigr)} 
   &&\text{for $V<0$}\\[1em]
V_{\textrm{RESET}} &= V\bigl(\arg(\grad(\smooth(I)) \leqslant 0)(0)\bigr) 
   &&\text{for $V>0$}\\[1em]
I_{\textrm{RESET}} &= I\bigl(\arg(\grad(\smooth(I)) \leqslant 0)(0)\bigr) 
   &&\text{for $V>0$}\\[1em]
V_{\textrm{SET,stop}}   &= \min(V) \\[1em]
V_{\textrm{RESET,stop}} &= \max(V) \\[1em]
I_{\textrm{cc}}    &= \min(I) \\[1em]
L_{\textrm{in}}    &= I(V=\pm 0.4)\big/I(V=\pm 0.2)
\end{alignat}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works just as I wanted it to be. Would you care to explain what difference the alignat environment makes? Is it the spacing between the equations and the condition?

Comment: Also, do you happen to know how to align the Variables before the equal signs at the left?

Comment: @Nils - The `align` environment doesn't allow you to exert direct control over the horizontal space between the groups of columns; in practice, you may get more horizontal space than what's optimal. With `alignat`, *you* are in charge of telling LaTeX how much horizontal whitespace (here: `\quad`) should be inserted.

Comment: @Nils - I would *not* left-align the variable names. However, if you absolutely must, change `alignat{2}` to `alignat{3}`, prefix a `&` character at the start of all 8 rows, and change all 8 instances of `&=` to `&&=`.

Comment: Thanks so much for the heads up :)