How to get equal vertical spacing between all lines of a multiline equation? And should it be done? (EDITED)
Consider the following MWE:
\documentclass[]{article}

% PACKAGES LOADING

\usepackage[]{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
    f(x)&=(1/n)(x)\\
    &=(1/n)\sum_{i\in N}x_i\\
    &=(1/n)\sum_{i\in N}y_i
\end{align}

\end{document}

Which produces this output:

Is there any way to force the vertical space between the first and the second rows to be identical to the space between the second and the third rows without shrinking the summations?
EDIT Thanks to the comments, I know now the following code does the trick:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\savebox\strutbox{$\vphantom{\displaystyle\sum_{i\in N}}$}
\begin{align}
    f(x)&=(1/n)(x)\\
    &=(1/n)\vphantom{\prod}\sum_{i\in N}x_i\\
    &=(1/n)\sum_{i\in N}y_i
\end{align}

\end{document}

Yielding:

Unfortunately, I can’t quite decide which one looks better.
Hence, should I do it? What would you do?

Very old problem without feasible automatic solution. Basically you have to introduce \vphantoms, see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9147/82917

Thank you for your comment and the related question. Is it generally considered bad typesetting practice to do what I am asking for? Also, how come it has no solution if it’s such an old problem?

I don't think it's bad typesetting at all! As for why there is no automatic solution: surely you can make align find out the largest height, and introduce automatic struts in every row. I believe this won't happen for at least two reasons: (1) Twenty-something years of document will give different output; (2) We'll get a bunch of questions like "Line spacing in align is too big, how can I reduce it?"

In ConTeXt one can obtain something of this sort by setting the interlinespace key of the formula to a higher value. In this example I set it to 1.75\lineheight and that seemed to be sufficient. There is probably a similar way to do the same in LaTeX that I am not aware of. (I think I prefer the formula without this adjustment.)

Thank you all for your comments. I have tried to follow the approach in the linked question, but I didn’t succeed. The reason is that changing \savebox\strutbox{$\vphantom{\dfrac11}$} for \savebox\strutbox{$\vphantom{\sum_{i\in N}$} does not do trick. Any idea why?

\dfrac forces \displaystyle, \sum does not, so you'll need $\vphantom{\displaystyle\sum_{i\in N}$. But be careful with grouping, defining it at document level will affect everything (equations, tables, arrays, ...)

Thank you! This last comment solves the question.

"Which one looks better" is in general highly subjective. I believe we might all agree that the first one won't win any beauty pageant, but personally I'd go just with \\[1ex] after the first line, as the uneven spacing doesn't really bother me. Bat again, highly subjective. I fear that as it stands after the edit the question has no objective answer.
